# Stop timer set new value and start again AVR (Interrupt)

Tags: timer, arduino, microcontroller, interrupt, avr

I have AVR MCU.
I am playing with timer now.
What I need ? I have timer counting up with some frequency. In each interrupt I am incrementing variable, and somewhere I need to check value of this variable and if equals 100, I need to stop timer count, set new value for frequency and continue counting down.
I cannot get how to stop timer and set new value to compare.
I have tried to select no clock source using mux selector register, but it continue to count up.
What is correct way to do this. 
Here is my code

```
// Arduino timer CTC interrupt example
// www.engblaze.com

// avr-libc library includes
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define LEDPIN_UP 9
#define LEDPIN_DOWN 8
int current_value = 0;
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);  
   // pinMode(LEDPIN_UP, OUTPUT);

    // initialize Timer1
    cli();          // disable global interrupts
    TCCR1A = 0;     // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
    TCCR1B = 0;     // same for TCCR1B

    // set compare match register to desired timer count:
   // OCR1A = 3123;
    OCR1A = 1562;
    // turn on CTC mode:
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
    // Set CS10 and CS12 bits for 1024 prescaler:
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10);
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);
    // enable timer compare interrupt:
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
    // enable global interrupts:
    sei();
}

void loop()
{
    //digitalWrite(LEDPIN_UP, current_value);
  Serial.println(current_value);
       if(current_value==255) {
      TCCR1B |= (0 << CS10);
      TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12);
      Serial.println("Reseting timer");
    }
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    current_value++;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  TCCR1B |= (0 << CS10);
  TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12);
```

does not do what you are expecting. Since you are using "or" `|`, the value placed back is `0|1` which is 1, not 0 like you desire.

The usual way to clear a bit is

```
  TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS10);
```

To clear two bits at once, use

```
  TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS10 | 1 << CS12);
```

As for counting down, you will want to use a variable to indicate which direction you are currently going, and then use that variable in the ISR. Perhaps,

```
int dir = 1;

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    current_value += dir;
}
```

and change dir to -1 when you want it to count down instead.